# RESTEasy Service example with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, resteasy

I cannot get my REST-Service working. Can anybody help me finding the error?
I think it is something wrong about the artifact I defined, but I am not sure.

Service class:

```
package services;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class MessageRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>LES.Core.WebServices</display-name>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>LES.Core.WebServices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Artifacts
[image: Artifacts]

Modules
[image: Modules]

Project structure
[image: Project structure]

Tomcat run definition:
[image: Tomcat run definition]

When I navigate to `http://localhost:6655/LES.Core.WebServices/rest/message/name` I get 404 error.

EDIT: For those, who want to try, here my project, just unzip it.
http://www.filedropper.com/lescorewebservices

Comment: Not too familiar with REST-Easy. but in your `web.xml` file; defining your resteasy-servlet as a HTTPServletDispatcher doesn't sound correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be many issus with your project setup and here down a list of bulletpoints showing what should be done for minimum to get your application deployed successfully:

- Create a new folder entitled ***webapp*** under the *$PROJECT/src/main/* folder and move the *$PROJECT/web/WEB-INF* folder into it (This is a default webapp project structure recognized by *Maven*).
- Add a new `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclass to bootstrap your services configuration. The application path should match your desired one:

```java
@ApplicationPath( "/rest" )
public class SampleApplication extends Application
{

    private static final Set< Object > singletons = new HashSet< Object >();

    public SampleApplication()
    {
        singletons.add( new MessageRestService() );
    }

    @Override
    public Set< Class< ? > > getClasses()
    {
        HashSet< Class< ? > > set = new HashSet< Class< ? > >();
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set< Object > getSingletons()
    {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

- Add the `SampleApplication` as the *javax.ws.rs.Application* init-param for the HttpDispatcherServlet under the webapp deployment descriptor *web.xml*:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>app.SampleApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

- Add a `<packaging>war</packaging>` element to your project *pom.xml* file so that the project is recognized to be a **web application** and can be deployed under Tomcat AS.
- In the *Tomcat Application Run Configuration*, go to the *Deployment* tab, click on the *+* button and choose *Artifact* as a type then add your module as a webapp.
- Run the tomcat configuration and your should see something as below highlighting that your REST application has been successfully discovered:

  > XXX INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher. Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class SampleApplication

Comment: The access point would be of the form *http://host:port/context_path/rest/...* and where the *context_path* will vary depending on the one you used to deploy your application.